# Post to twitter timeline without it posting to Facebook if accounts are linked

Tags: ios, facebook, api, twitter

In iOS5 my app I allow the user to share to both Twitter and Facebook, Recently I've noticed that when a user who has linked their twitter account to Facebook shares to twitter using

```
statuses/update.json
```

Then that post will be posted to their Facebook timeline.

If, in my app, they have decided to share to Facebook too, then they will see an "almost identical but not quite" additional posting on their Facebook timeline from twitter.

So, is there a param I can pass to statuses/update.json that will tell twitter not to post this tweet to the users Facebook timeline?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full solution, but: "Retweets, @replies, and DMs will not post to your Facebook profile"

http://support.twitter.com/articles/200773-i-x2019-m-having-trouble-using-twitter-with-facebook

Comment: Yeah, thats not really what I'm looking for, I've looked all over twitter and they don't seem to have anything, so apart from registering a twitter id for my app and having it @name at the front of all tweets there doesn't seem to be a solution.